# Scala error when running test in new application. can't expand macros?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am trying to learn the basics of Scala, scalatest, and sbt and I'm following a tutorial. This is my `built.sbt` file:

```
name := "demo-hello"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.1.0" % "test"
```

I have a test that looks like this (showing this is probably unnecessary:

```
package demo

import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class HelloTest extends FunSuite {
  test("say hello method works correctly") {
    val hello = new Hello
    assert(hello.sayHello("Scala") == "Hello, Scala!")
  }
}
```

What should I do from here? I am trying to run the test but I get this error:

```
Error:(8, 36) can't expand macros compiled by previous versions of Scala
    assert(hello.sayHello("Scala") == "Hello, Scala!")
```

I'm not that familiar with the `%` symbol btw.

**FIX**

I changed my `build.sbt` to this:

```
name := "demo-hello"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.1.0" % "test"
```

Remaining questions:

1. So it seems downgrading to scalaVersion "2.10" worked. Why?
2. What is an artifact? `scalatest` is apparently an artifact?
3. Where is scalaversion 2.10 kept on my machine? It seems I only have scala 2.12. Where in my project folder is version 2.10?

Comment: `"org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2." % "2.1.0" % "test"` looks weird. Could you try to change it as `"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.0" % "test"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions slightly out-of-order:

2 - An "artifact" is something that's built by maven, sbt, or another build system. For Scala or Java, this is almost always a jar file. Each item in `libraryDependencies` specifies a file in a maven repository (a database of artifacts).

1 - Scala class files are not compatible between minor versions of Scala. When you download a Scala jar from a maven repository, the Scala version is specified as part of the artifact name. The `_2.10` in your dependency declares that you wish to use the version of `scalatest` that's compile for Scala 2.10 - which is why you were getting an error using it in your Scala 2.12 application.

When declaring dependencies on Scala artifacts in sbt, you should always use the `%%` operator, which automatically appends the appropriate suffix to your artifact, like so:

```
// This works for any scalaVersion setting.
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.0" % "test"
```

3 - `sbt` handles downloading the appropriate runtime files for the declared version of Scala automatically.